# Unable to download file by its id from Google Drive

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-drive-api

```
$ pip3 list | grep googl
google-api-python-client 1.7.9    
google-auth              1.6.3    
google-auth-httplib2     0.0.3    
google-auth-oauthlib     0.4.0
```

I can successfully list files shared to me. But I get "File not found" error when I try to download an existing file by its id. How to download a file by its id?

Script to list files

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
import io
import sys
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']
TOKEN_FILE = 'tockenRead.pickle'

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists(TOKEN_FILE):
        with open(TOKEN_FILE, 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server()
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open(TOKEN_FILE, 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Drive v3 API
    results = service.files().list(
        q="mimeType != 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'",
        pageSize=10,
        fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)"
    ).execute()
    items = results.get('files', [])

    if not items:
        print('No files found.')
    else:
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Result

```
$ python3 list_files.py 
Files:
20140810_125633.mp4 (1SwYm5Z1zPczZnDulmsbA9wrEJ-JT-hwE)
Getting started (0B3K2QXOGSOFRc3RhcnRlcl9maWxl)
```

Script to download file with id 1SwYm5Z1zPczZnDulmsbA9wrEJ-JT-hwE

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
import io
import sys
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']
TOKEN_FILE = 'tokenWrite.pickle';

def downloadFile(driveService, fileId):
    request = driveService.files().get_media(fileId=fileId)
    fh = io.BytesIO()
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
    done = False
    while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
        print ("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists(TOKEN_FILE):
        with open(TOKEN_FILE, 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server()
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open(TOKEN_FILE, 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    downloadFile(service, '1SwYm5Z1zPczZnDulmsbA9wrEJ-JT-hwE')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Error

```
$ python3 download_files.py 
Please visit this URL to authorize this application: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=619229308650-91gkhdgo7v0jbt6df1phahmq868eb7gd.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive.file&state=4mP9kgVJQD4ETOu5JjIRQFBLcyViAG&access_type=offline&code_challenge=ybCzMgZ2SOXdrpZZYn1dq9nSJk8wMtLo7Deg_Xix9So&code_challenge_method=S256
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "download_files.py", line 52, in <module>
    main()
  File "download_files.py", line 49, in main
    downloadFile(service, '1SwYm5Z1zPczZnDulmsbA9wrEJ-JT-hwE')
  File "download_files.py", line 21, in downloadFile
    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 705, in next_chunk
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self._uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1SwYm5Z1zPczZnDulmsbA9wrEJ-JT-hwE?alt=media returned "File not found: 1SwYm5Z1zPczZnDulmsbA9wrEJ-JT-hwE.">
```

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this answer?

#### Reason of issue:

When I saw your scripts, I noticed that the scope of below script are different from the above script. I think that this is the reason of your issue.

At above script, `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly` is used. On the other hand, at the below script, `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` is used.

[The official document](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#drivev3) says about the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` as follows.

> View and manage Google Drive files and folders that you have opened or created with this app

This means that when your script uploads a file using the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`, you can retrieve the file using the scope. But for example, when the file is manually upload to the Google Drive, the file cannot be downloaded by the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`, even when the file is shared with you.

In order to download the file, how about the following workarounds?

#### Workaround 1:

You use the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` or `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` instead of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`.

#### Workaround 2:

If you are required to use the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`, it uploads the file using the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`. By this, the file can be downloaded by the scope.

#### Note:

- **When you change the scopes, please remove the file of `tokenWrite.pickle` and authorize the scopes again and create new `tokenWrite.pickle`. By this, you can use new scopes. Please be careful this.**

#### Reference:

- [Scopes of Drive API, v3](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#drivev3)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.